# CustomIOS7alertview behaviour

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

I'm using Customios7alertview from github. I face some issues against keyboard representaion.
when I clik add button aletview appears with text view and some buttons. When i click on text view to enter text some times keyboard apper under the alert view. At that time i'm unable to use key board to enter text. But sometimes it works correctly.

Comment: Enter a bug on that github site, hopefully the author will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code from:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] addSubview:self];
```

to:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:self];
```